# How can i link submit button on gravity form to a popup created with elementor

Tags: forms, hyperlink, popup, elementor, gravity

I am new and i do have a question regarding gravity forms and elementor.

I have created and designed a very nice popup window as template with elementor and I would like to use it with gravity submission form.

Basically it should be displayed as a popup window when submit button is triggered.

does anyone have an idea how I can do it?

thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the Dynamic option in a link? It will display a list of options and if i'm correct it will give you an option to choose Elementor Pop-up!